# Google Calendar API Gives More Info Than Desired

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I am a beginner programmer so pls no hate.

I have the following call:

```
        eevents = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token, timeMax = "2022-07-01T00:00:00Z",
                                       timeMin = "2022-06-28T00:00:00Z").execute()
        for event in events['items']:
            print(event.items())
        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
           break
```

But I get events outside the the specified time frame such as:|

```
('start', {'dateTime': '2022-05-02T10:00:00+02:00', 'timeZone': 'Europe/Prague'}), ('end', {'dateTime': '2022-05-02T11:00:00+02:00', 'timeZone': 'Europe/Prague'}),
```

Additionally, the expected response at https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list is the following:

```
{
"kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": etag,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "items": [
    events Resource
  ]
}
```

But in addition to the expected dictionary keys and values I get information in tuples. eg.:

```
('kind', 'calendar#event'), ('etag', '"3306952077924000"'), ('id', '5qcpuj5r1k35v533slhljtgh9g'), ('status', 'confirmed')
```

This second thing kind of makes sense. I have more than the baseline information in the event, so there is more info adde but since it is more than expected it gets added into tuples.

It really is the first issue of getting events outside scope that bothers me. The second issue is just hunch that the two things could be related.

Comment: For the second question, you are printing event.items(). Event is a dict, and items() method returns a list of key,value tuples. [Here is the structure of events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource), there is no extra information.

Comment: For the events outside specified time frame, are they recurring? You might need singleEvents=True.

Comment: Hopefully this helps, but next time post two questions. It is easier for others who might have the same issue to find.

Comment: Thank you you answered both questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the title question:

`for event in events['items']:` is looping through the events, where events is a dict specified [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource)

`event.items()` returns a list of key value pairs as tuples. There is no extra information.